# Show that $a \equiv b$ (mod $n$) if and only if $r = s$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Write $a = qn + r$ and $b =q'n+s$ with $q,q' \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $r, s \in \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ according to the divion algorithm.

Show that $a \equiv b$ (mod $n$) if and only if $r = s$.

My attempt: 
Proof. ($\Rightarrow$) Suppose that $a \equiv b$ (mod $n$). This implies that $n \mid a-b$ and $a - b =(qn+r)-(q'n+s)= n(q-q')+(r-s) = nk$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $n \mid (r-s)$, then $(\star)\hspace{1mm} r-s = nc$ for some $c \in \mathbb{Z}$, but if $r = n-1$ and $s = 0$, then $(\star)$ becomes $n-1 = nc$, which does not hold for any $c \in \mathbb{Z}$. It follows that $n \nmid r-s$ unless $r-s = 0$, demonstrating that $r = s.$
$(\Leftarrow)$ For the other side, suppose that $r = s$. Then $r- s = 0$, and $a- b = (qn+r)-(q'n+s) = n(q-q') + (r-s) = n(q-q') + 0 = nq - nq' = nk.$ It follows that $a \equiv b$ (mod $n).\hspace{1mm} \Box$

I know that in proving the $(\Rightarrow)$ part, I made an error. I did not really show that $r-s = 0$. My TA said tha I would need to show that $|r-s| < n$ in order to show $r-s = 0$, but I'm not entirely sure why this is the case. I know that since $r$ and $s$ are remainders, so $0 \leq r \leq n$ and $0 \leq s \leq n$. How do I show that $|r-s| < n$, and why does this prove that $r-s$ must be $0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have done all the steps to show that $|r-s|<n$ - you just haven't said them explicitly. When you wrote "if $r=n-1$ and $s=0$", what you're saying is $$|r-s| \le n-1 - 0 = n-1 < n$$
which is exactly what you needed to show.

---

There is however a cleaner way to do this question.

We have $$\begin{align}a \equiv b \pmod n &\iff (q-q')n + (r-s) \equiv 0\pmod n\\&\iff (r-s) \equiv 0 \pmod n\\&\iff r\equiv s \pmod n\end{align}$$

But $0\le r,s\le n-1$, so we must have $r=s$.

Comment: Good answer, thanks.